# After SAP GUI Update to 7.40, VBA can't connect any more

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

so I made a handful of macros on SAP GUI 7.30 a few months ago, but my company recently required everyone to update to SAP GUI 7.40. None of my macros working anymore as it is having some sort of issue connecting to the SAPGUI.

Up until now I have used this code to connect excel to SAP

```
Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")  'Get the SAP GUI Scripting object
  Set SAPApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine 'Get the currently running SAP GUI
  Set SAPCon = SAPApp.Children(0) 'Get the first system that is currently connected
  Set session = SAPCon.Children(0) 'Get the first session (window) on that connection
```

But now I am receiving error : '-2147221020 (800401e4)' after the first line
Which is an Automation error and invalid syntax.

Does anyone know how I can update my sheets to fix this issue?

Comment: Does anyone know where the object "SAPGUI" is being pulled from? My only thought at this point is that the file/ program no longer exists in that location so I am trying to determine where to check for that.

Answer (score 1):

Okay upon reinstalling SAP I was given both the standard SAP logon pad and the newer SAP business client. The interface looked different in the business client but still contained script recording. I recorded and noticed that

```
Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
```

was now

```
Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUISERVER")
```

This reconnected me to SAP correctly as it did before I upgraded from 7.3 to 7.4. It still will not connect if I use the logon pad for some reason but this is better than nothing. Basically the same, just a different look.